# Rendering a report based on variable in COGNOS Report Studio 10.2.2

Tags: variables, reporting-services, rendering, cognos

I am designing a report in IBM Cognos Report Studio 10.2.2 that includes a list of different types of disabilities and the count of employees that have each type of disability. However, this list is only supposed to display if there are at least 10 employees with some kind of disability.

I tried solving this problem by creating a separate query (Disability summary) with a data item (Disabled) where each employee gets a 1 if they have a disability and 0 otherwise. I then added another data item (Number disabled) that I define as:

```
total([Disabled]) for report
```

I then create a Boolean variable in the Condition Explorer (Disabilities Reportable) which I define as:

```
[Disability Summary].[Number disabled] >= 10
```

Next, for the list that displays the count for each type of disability, I set the Render Variable to Disabilities Reportable. I also place a singleton elsewhere on the report page and set the query to Disability Summary and check Number disabled as a property. I also insert the Number disabled data item in the singleton.

However, when I run the report, I get the following RSV-VAL-0032 error:

```
The following expression is not valid: [Disability Summary].[Number disabled] &gt; = 10.
If the item exists in a query but is not referenced in the layout, add it to a property
list. CRX-API-0005 An error occurred at or near the position &#39;0&#39;. The variable named
&#39;[Disability Summary].[Number disabled]&#39; is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

Render Variables need to be accessible to the Page where they are used.  If it works in a Report Expression, it will work in a Render Variable.

This means you must use prompt variables, built in Report Functions, or the query that is tied directly to the Report Page.

Assign the query that you are pulling your disability count from to the Report Page, then set the disability count field as a 'Property'.  This makes the field accessible to the report for formatting and Report Expressions.

Click anywhere in your report, then on the properties panel click the Up Arrow to drill up the the very top, the 'Page' level.  (Alternatively, Page Explorer->Report Pages->Double Click the Page you are working on)

Define the 'Query' and 'Properties'.

Creating a separate summary query is perfectly acceptable.  If your summary is at a different aggregate level than the details of your list, Cognos is going to create a separate query and make separate database trips anyway. Use whatever method works and makes sense for you.